# ES6 javascript block scope variable hoisting into for header

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, hoisting

Are all of the block scope variables in a for loop block hoisted above the loop header itself?

```
    var x = 4;

    for(let i = 3; i < x; i++) {
        let x = 2;
        ...
    }
```

Should this produce a dead-zone error on x every time i is compared to x in the loop header?  I understand i is pushed down in the block scope, but why not x?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm adding block scoped variables  into my  javascript-database interpreter and I need to know how to handle this case properly.  But, I think the correct approach is to treat the loop block as nested into the loop header.  That way the `let i` in the header is visible in the loop block, but the `let x` in the loop block isn't visible in the loop header.

Comment: Not sure what issue is? Why do you define `let x = 2` within `for` loop if `var x = 4` is defined outside of `for` loop?

Comment: My question was that `i` is part of the loop block scope, but in which scope do I search for `x`?  If both `i` and `x` are in the same scope I should get a dead-zone error -- e.g. if the block scope hoisting continues through the loop header to pick  up the header's declaration of `let i` and  it's going to already have the loop's declaration of `let x` as well.  Hence a dead-zone on `x` in the header.

Comment: Still not following. What is "header"? What is "dead-zone error"? Are you trying to re-define `x` within `for` loop? Or is requirement for `let x = 2` to throw a `TypeError` within `for` loop? What is expected result?

Comment: A `for` statement has a `loop header` for the control variables, and a `loop body` that iterates those variables.  Yes, I'm defining an `x` in the `loop body`.  Is this scoped definition of `x` part of the same block scope as the loop header definition of `i`?

Comment: Given example at Question `let i = 3` and `let x = 2` should only be accessible within `for` loop. That is purpose of using `let`, yes?

Comment: @Malbrain please refer to my answer, I have addressed both of your questions. Because `let x` is declared inside the block scope it has no access to the loop header, it only has access to the loop body. The `x` in loop header is referencing `var x`

Answer (score 2):

The relevant section of the language specification is [13.7.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-statement)

If the `for` statement contains a `let` or `const` declaration then a scope is created.

Each iteration creates a scope, if the `for` statement contains a `let` declaration.

If the for body is a block then a scope is created.

Here are some examples and the scopes that are created:

```
//no scope
for(i = 0; i<3; i++) console.log(i);

//no scope
for(var i = 0; i<3; i++) console.log(i);

//for scope and iteration scope
for(let i = 0; i<3; i++) console.log(i);


// for scope, iteration scope and block scope
for(let i = 0; i<3; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Why do we need iteration scopes? For closures:

```
for(let i = 0; i<3; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 10);
}
```

Output without iteration scope: 3,3,3. With iteration scope: 0,1,2

Comment: Thanks for  pointing out the relevant ECMA standard section.  It is, as I surmised, creating nested scopes, one for any loop header `let`, then if needed, a second, nested, one for any `let` in the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

> Are all of the block scope variables in a for loop block hoisted above the loop header itself?

No, they are hoisted in the block scope

> Should this produce a dead-zone error on x every time i is compared to x in the loop header? I understand i is pushed down in the block scope, but why not x?

No, because `x` in the loop header is referencing `x` defined as 4 `var x = 4`

You cannot access a `let` variable before it has been declared as that time between scoping and declaration is the TDZ.

ex.

```
console.log(x) // Reference Error, x is in TDZ
let x = 4
console.log(x) // --> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: test run]

based on that, i think let x are only available in that for scope.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood, and thought that there would be only one block scope.  I balked at taking the two arbitrary variables in the expression `i < x` and having to decide which block scope to look them up, which is impossible to determine.

The correct approach is to build two nested block scopes, one for the loop header and  one for the loop body.  That means `let i` is seen in both the loop header and the loop body scopes, and the `let x` in the loop is only seen in the loop body scope.  Easy peasy, lemon squeezy.

Comment: _"The correct approach is to build two nested block scopes"_ The for statement is not a block and the for body doesn't have to be one. So e.g. `for (let i = 0; i<10; i++) console.log(i);` creates just one scope and it's not a block scope.

Comment: Right, that's exactly what I said:  the loop header creates a scope to contain the `let i = 0;` and in your case, there would not be a nested loop body scope.  But when the loop body is a block, a block scope for it would be created, nested within the loop header scope.